# When to use 頭の毛 and 髪

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Not sure if this question's been asked before (I searched beforehand but nothing came up, so), but I just came across this sentence : "今一番大切なのは頭の毛だ。", and I'm not having any comprehension problems linked to vocabulary and such, but I was always under the impression that to say "hair" (on one's head), it's "髪" (kami) that a person should use ? When should "頭の毛" be privileged instead of "髪", and doesn't "毛", when meaning hair, mostly designates body hair in specific ?

Comment: 「身体の他の部分の毛ではなく、特に頭の毛」と、対比・強調したいときにこう言うと思います（"「脇毛」や「胸毛」など、場所によって毛を区別する場合、「頭の毛」か「髪の毛」といった表現がされ" ([語源由来辞典](http://gogen-allguide.com/ka/kami_hair.html))）。特に、ハゲ・薄毛の人が頭頂部の毛を気にして言うときに…。

Answer (score 2):

The English word "hair" is translated as [髪]{かみ}、髪の[毛]{け}、[毛髪]{もうはつ}、[頭髪]{とうはつ} in Japanese.

[頭]{あたま}の毛 isn't wrong but it is not common.